# MySQL v8.0 released. Will CiviCRM work with it?

Tags: mysql-8.0

MySQL 8.0 has been released.  Will CiviCRM work with it?  I tried migrating a test database to it, and CiviCRM under Joomla failed.

```
Oct 31 12:36:35  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array (
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] =>  SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
       civicrm_option_group_en_GB g WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id   AND  g.name            = 'languages'   AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge")) )  ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
       civicrm_option_group_en_G' at line 1]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] =>  SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
       civicrm_option_group_en_GB g WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id   AND  g.name            = 'languages'   AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge")) )  ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
       civicrm_option_group_en_G' at line 1]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=" SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
       civicrm_option_group_en_GB g WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id   AND  g.name            = 'languages'   AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge")) )  ORDER BY v.weight [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grouping FROM   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
       civicrm_option_group_en_G' at line 1]"] )
```

The SQL below runs happily against MySQL 5.7 whilst it fails against MySQL 8.0 with

> "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version,
>   expecting '(', WITH

SQL:

> SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as grouping FROM
>   civicrm_option_value_en_GB v,
>          civicrm_option_group_en_GB g WHERE  v.option_group_id = g.id   AND  g.name            = 'languages'   AND  g.is_active       = 1  AND
>   v.is_active = 1  AND ( v.component_id IS NULL  OR v.component_id IN
>   (SELECT id FROM civicrm_component WHERE name IN
>   ("CiviEvent","CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviPledge"))
>   )  ORDER BY v.weight

Replacing the first line with:

> SELECT  v.label as label ,v.name as value, v.grouping as `grouping`

solves the problem.

Clearly some work is needed before CiviCRM will work with MySQL 8.0

Comment: When answering your own question, there's a checkbox indicating that you want to answer it yourself.  This lets others chime in separately later, and your answer can be up/downvoted separately from the question.  You may want to edit this to put your answer separately.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly CiviCRM won't work with MySQL 8.9 yet; at least not in my environment.